# ¿Cómo se retorna una función correctamente?

Tags: java

en un ejercicio que estoy haciendo de java que es un juego de ahorcado de dos jugadores donde tiene que tener un menú en el cual si aprietas "1" añadirías una palabra para que el otro jugador adivine y te devuelva otra vez al menú para apretar "2" y que inicie el juego  pero tengo ciertos errores de conversión y de lógica como char[] cannot be convert to string cuando llamo algunos datos de una función y eso, así que me gustaría saber cual es la mejor forma para que mi código compile correctamente Muchas Gracias.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ahorcado {
    // Variables Globales
    static String palabraInicial;
    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    static int puntuacion = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //el método main por ahora lo dejamos solo para iniciar el juego
        //declaramos un array de caracteres vacío
        char[] palabra = {};
        //llamamos al método menú y le pasamos el array por parámetro
        metodoMenu(palabra);
    }
    public static void metodoMenu(char[] palabra){
        //declaramos la variable opcion de tipo byte
        byte opcion;
        //evaluamos que el array de caracteres sea distinto de cero
        if (palabra.length != 0){
            //si lo es, imprimimos el texto iniciamos juego
            System.out.println("INICIAMOS JUEGO");
            //asignamos el valor 2 a la variable opcion
            opcion = 2;
        }
        else{
            //si el array de caracteres está vacío, imprimimos la bienvenida
            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL JUEGO AHORCADO");  
            //llamamos al método menú y recibimos el resultado de la opción deseada
            opcion = menu(); 
        }    
      
    boolean salir=false; 
    //iniciamos las opciones en función de la opción elegida
    switch (opcion) {
                //si es uno
                case 1: 
                    //llamamos al método añadir palabra y recibimos la palabra como array de caracteres
                    palabra = añadirPalabra();
                    //volvemos a llamar al método menú y le pasamos el array como parámetro
                    metodoMenu(palabra);
                    break;
                //en caso de querer iniciar el juego
                case 2: 
                    //si el array de caracteres tiene alguna letra, aquí por no complicar mucho el código no se evalúa que solo se puedan introducir caracteres, que para elo podrías hacer un método a parte que lo hiciera
                    if (palabra.length != 0){
                        //llamamos al método iniciar juego y le enviamos el array por parámetro
                        iniciarJuego(palabra);
                    }
                    else{
                        //si el array está vacío, damos el aviso por pantalla
                        System.out.println("Para iniciar el juego tiene que añadir una palabra");     
                        //volvemos a llamar al método menú enviando el array vació como parámetro
                        metodoMenu(palabra);
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //salimos del programa
                    teclado.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;       
        }        
    }

    public static void iniciarJuego(char[] palabra){
        //limpiamos el bufer del teclado
        teclado.nextLine();
        //damos información de la longitud de la palabra
        System.out.println("La palabra a buscar tiene la siguiente longitud: " + palabra.length);
        //hayamos el número de espacios
        int espacios = palabra.length - 2;
        //imprimimos el primer caracter de la palabra (array de caracteres 0)
        System.out.print(palabra[0] + " ");
        //hacemos un bucle para dibujar los espacios
        for (int i = 0; i < espacios; i++) { //imprimo _ por cada letra que tenga la palabra
            System.out.print(" _ ");
        }
        //imprimimos el último caracter de la palabra
        System.out.print(" " + palabra[palabra.length - 1]);
        //imprimimos una línea en blanco
        System.out.println("");
        
         String jugada;
            char[] palabraJugador2 = new char[palabra.length];
            int caracteresAnterior = palabra.length / 2; //si no varia el numero de '_' en cada tirada significa
            //que no ha introducido un caracter valido y pierde una vida
            int caracteresActual;
            int espacios2 = palabraJugador2.length - 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < espacios2; i++) { //imprimo _ por cada letra que tenga la palabra
            System.out.print(" _ ");
        }
            
            while (puntuacion < 5) { //si llega a perder 5 vidas el jugador pierde

                System.out.println("Numero de vidas restantes: " + (puntuacion - 5) + " de 5.");

                System.out.println("Introduzca una letra: ");
                jugada = teclado.next();

                while (jugada.length() != 1) { //Validacion de la entrada del jugador 2
                    System.out.println("Introduzca SOLO una letra: ");
                    jugada = teclado.nextLine();
                }

                palabraJugador2 = comportamiento(jugada, palabra, palabraJugador2); //comprueba si la letra esta en la palabra

                for (int m = 0; m < palabraJugador2.length; m++) { //imprimo lo que ve el usuario
                    System.out.print(palabraJugador2[m]);
                }
                System.out.println();

                caracteresActual = contarCaracteres(palabraJugador2, '_');
                if (caracteresActual == 0) {
                    puntuacion = 6; //si puntuacion vale 6 es que el usuario ha ganado la partida
                }

                 if (caracteresActual == caracteresAnterior) { // compruebo si las '_' han variado en el turno para que pierda una vida
                    puntuacion++;
                }
                intentos(puntuacion);
                caracteresAnterior = caracteresActual;
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Juego finalizado");
        }
    
    
public static String[] comportamiento (String jugada, String palabra, String []palabraJugador2){
            //ejecuta la jugada y devuelve la palabra modificada si ha acertado alguna letra

            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length(); i++) {
                if (palabra.charAt(i) == jugada.charAt(0)) {
                    palabraJugador2[i] = jugada;
                }
            }
            return palabraJugador2;
    }
    public static char[] añadirPalabra() {
        //limpiamos el bufer del teclado
        teclado.nextLine();
            //pedimos la palabra por teclado
            System.out.println("Jugador 1 introduzca la palabra deseada (sin numeros ni espacios)");
            //almacenamos la palabra (Suponiendo que solo se introuzca una palabra, pues no lo evaluamos), en la variable palabraInicial
            palabraInicial = teclado.nextLine();
            //no la uso
            String palabraAux = palabraInicial;
            //palabraInicial = "";

            //declaramos un array de caracteres denominado palabra formado por palabraInicial
            char[] palabra = palabraInicial.toCharArray();
            //retornamos el array de caracteres
            return palabra;
    }

    public static void dibujoIntentos(){

    }

    public static byte menu() {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("1. Ingresa Palabra");
        System.out.println("2. Jugar");
        System.out.println("3. Salir");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opcion: ");
        return teclado.nextByte();
    }

    public static void intentos ( int puntuacion){

            switch (puntuacion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println ("------\n" +
                   "|  \n" +
                   "| \n" +
                   "| \n" +
                   "| \n" +
                   "| \n" +
                   "|_ \n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                   System.out.println("------\n" +
        "|  |\n" +
        "|  o\n" +
        "| \n" +
        "| \n" +
        "| \n" +
        "|_ \n");

                    break;
                case 3:
                   System.out.println("------\n" +
        "|  |\n" +
        "|  o\n" +
        "| /|\\\n" +
        "| \n" +
        "| \n" +
        "|_ \n");

                    break;
                case 4:
                      System.out.println("------\n" +
        "|  |\n" +
        "|  o\n" +
        "| /|\\\n" +
        "| / \\\n" +
        "|\n" +
        "|_");

                    break;
                case 5:
                     System.out.println("------\n" +
        "|  |\n" +
        "|  o\n" +
        "| /|\\\n" +
        "| / \\\n" +
        "|\n" +
        "|_");
                     System.out.println("Muerto :c");
                    break;
                case 6:
               System.out.println("------\n" +
        "|  \n" +
        "|  \n" +
        "|  o\n" +
        "| /|\\\n" +
        "| / \\\n" +
        "|_");
                    System.out.println("Vivo :D");
                    break;
            }
    }
    
    public static int contarCaracteres (String cadena,char caracter){
            int posicion, contador = 0;
            //se busca la primera vez que aparece
            posicion = cadena.indexOf(caracter);
            while (posicion != -1) { //mientras se encuentre el caracter
                contador++;           //se cuenta
                //se sigue buscando a partir de la posición siguiente a la encontrada
                posicion = cadena.indexOf(caracter, posicion + 1);
            }
            return contador;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola @JuanAHenao, veo que has empleado el código de mi respuesta a tu anterior pregunta. Como podrás comprobar en la comunidad, hay enlaces para preguntas sin responder. Para cerrar tu anterior pregunta y marcarla como contestada, te sugiero entrar en ella y darle al check de respuesta aceptada. Un saludo

Comment: Bueno, pues yo considero ésta, una comunidad participativa, en la que unos hacen o hacemos preguntas, y otros, en función de sus conocimientos, las responden. Y que menos que por parte de los primeros, los que preguntan, demuestren agradecimiento a los segundos, los que responden, y o bien les otorgan reputación agradeciendo dicha respuesta, o bien, si ésta les resultó de provecho y era lo que preguntaban, la marcan como aceptada. No se el resto de la comunidad, pero yo mientras no marques tu anterior pregunta como aceptada, no te responderé la actual. Un saludo

Comment: Ah vale es que soy nuevo en la comunidad y todavía no conozco muchas cosas intente darte un me gusta pero me aparecía que no podía, y lo de mostrar completado con el chulo no lo sabia, tu respuesta me ayudo demasiado a proseguir con el ejercicio Muchas gracias, así que decidí preguntar otra vez ya que me quedaba poco para terminarlo.

Comment: Te recomiendo mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask].. y por lo menos, en esta pregunta, no hay un problema concreto. Trata de que tus preguntas sean sobre un problema concreto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como sabes el mundo de la programación es muy personal, y aunque los métodos y las funciones son comunes para todos, las formas de usarlas depende de los gustos de cada uno.

Como bien dice @gbianchi, tus preguntas son poco concretas, y resulta difícil entender donde tienes realmente el problema. Revisando tu código aparecen varios errores, y alguno no tiene que ver con tu pregunta.

De todas formas, yo te mostraré una forma muy pesonal de realizar el ejercicio. Creo que funciona de una forma muy básica, pues probar lo he probado, pero abría que afinar el código y depurar algún error que pueda ir saliendo, pero con él tendrás un código funcional que tú mismo podrás adecuar a tus necesidades.

```
public class Ahorcado {
    // Variables Globales
    static String palabraInicial;
    static Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //array de caracteres para transformar la palabra recibida por teclado
        char[] palabra = {};
        //llamamos al método ménú y enviamos el array por parámetro, en éste caso vacío
        metodoMenu(palabra);
    }
    public static void metodoMenu(char[] palabra){
        //variable byte para la opción
        byte opcion;
        //Condicional para comprobar que el array de caracteres tenga alguna letra
        if (palabra.length != 0){
            //si como dice la condición, es dintinto a cero, o sea, tiene algún dato escribimos "Iniciamos juego" y ponemos un 2 en la variable opcion
            System.out.println("INICIAMOS JUEGO");
            opcion = 2;
        }
        else{
            //si el array está vacío, no hay palabra, escribimos mensaje de bienvenida y mostramos menú, esperando respuesta en la variable opcion
            System.out.println("BIENVENIDO AL JUEGO AHORCADO");  
            opcion = menu(); 
        }   
        //condicionamos al valor de la variable opcion las diferentes posibilidades 
        switch (opcion) {
                //si la opción elegida en el menú es la 1
                case 1: 
                   //llamamos al método añadir palabra y recepcionamos la misma en la variable palabra
                    palabra = añadirPalabra();
                   //llamamos ahora al método menú y enviamos la palabra por parámetro
                    metodoMenu(palabra);
                    break;
               //si la opción elegida en el menú es la 2
                case 2: 
                    //si la variable palabra tiene algún caracter
                    if (palabra.length != 0){
                        //llamamos al método inicar juego y enviamos la palabra por parámetro
                        iniciarJuego(palabra);
                    }
                    else{
                        //si la palabra no tiene ningún caracter se lo decimos al usuario y llamamos al método menú enviando la vaiable vacía por palámetro
                        System.out.println("Para iniciar el juego tiene que añadir una palabra");     
                        metodoMenu(palabra);
                    }
                    break;
                //si la opción elegida en el menú es la 1
                case 3:
                   //cerramos la clase teclado
                   teclado.close();
                   //finalizamos el programa
                   System.exit(0);
                    break;
            }        
        }
        //método que inicia el juego y recibe el array de caracteres por parámetro
        public static void iniciarJuego(char[] palabra){
            //declaramos arrays de string para los dibujos del ahorcado
            String[] dibujoAhorcado = new String[7];
            String[] dibujoAhorcadoJuego = new String[7];
            //variable de string para la evolución del dibujo en función de los fallos en la introducción de la letra
            String dibujoAhorcadoF = "";
            //declaramos un contador de vidas y fallos
            int vidas = 7;
            int contadorFallos = 0;
            //variable booleana para resuelto
            boolean resuelto = false;
            //informamos al jugador del número de letras de la palabra
            System.out.println("La palabra a buscar tiene la siguiente longitud: " + palabra.length);
            //creamos una variable para el número de espacios de la letra descontando la letra inicial y final (-2), pues éstas se muestran
            int espacios = palabra.length - 2;
            //creamos una nueva variable con el valos de los espacios, pues espacios no variará
            int huecos = espacios;
            //creamos un nuevo array para los espacios
            char[] arrayEspacios = new char[espacios];
            //hacemos un bucle sobre el array anterior
            for (int i = 0; i < espacios; i++){
                //cada valor del array será el carácter "_"
                arrayEspacios[i] = '_';
            }
            //imprimimos en pantalla la primera letra del la palabra
            System.out.print(palabra[0] + " ");
            //bucle para los espacios
            for (int i = 0; i < espacios; i++) { 
                //imprimos _ por cada letra que teng la palabra descontando la primera y última letra que serán visibles
                System.out.print(" _ ");
             }
             //se imprime la última letra de la palabra
             System.out.print(" " + palabra[palabra.length - 1]);
             //pintamos línea en blanco para mejor visibilidad
             System.out.println("");

             //llamos al método dibujo inicial del ahorcado para recibirlo en el array dibujoAhorcadoJuego            
             dibujoAhorcadoJuego = dibujoInicial();

             //Este es el bucle pricipal del programa. Entrará en él, mientras vidas sea mayor a cero, y resuelto sea false          
             while ((vidas > 0) && (resuelto == false)){
                 //al entrar en el bucle, pone a cero el contador de fallos
                 contadorFallos = 0;
                 //Si hay huecos sin cubrir
                 if (huecos > 0){
                     //nos pedirá un letra
                     System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca una letra");
                     //recibe la letra por teclado, la expresión charAt(0) quiere decir que de todos los caracteres que escribas, el solo cogerá el primero
                     char letra = teclado.next().charAt(0);
                     //bucle para comparar si la letra está en la palabra
                     for (int i = 0; i < espacios; i++){
                         //la primera letra de la palabra la tenemos visible, por lo que comenzamos a buscar en 0 (primera letra) + 1 (segunda letra)
                         if (letra == palabra[i + 1]){
                             //cuando coincida la letra en su lugar en la palabra, mete dicha letra en el array de espacios
                             arrayEspacios[i] = letra;
                             //descuenta un hueco
                             huecos--;
                             //escribimos en pantalla la palabra mostrando la primera y última letra y las que se vayan encontrando
                             System.out.print(palabra[0] + " ");
                             for (int j = 0; j < arrayEspacios.length; j++){
                                 System.out.print(" " + arrayEspacios[j] + " ");
                             }
                             System.out.println(" " + palabra[palabra.length - 1]);
                         }
                         else{
                             //si la letra no está contenida en la palabra, aumentamos el contador de fallos en 1
                             contadorFallos++;
                             //para evitar que nos escriba un fallo por cada iteración del bucle de cada letra, hacemos éste condicionante, que espera a recorrer toda la palabra en función de los huecos, cuando las iteraciones coincidan con los huecos quiere decir que ya se han comprobado todas las letras y la buscada no está en la palabra
                             if (contadorFallos == espacios){
                                 //conjunto de opciones en función de las vidas que vayan quedando. Tenemos 7 dubujos posibles del ahoracado, se podrían hacer más o menos, así que tenemos 7 vidas ó 7 posibilidades de cometer un fallo
                                 switch (vidas){
                                     //en el primer fallo
                                     case 7:
                                        //dibujamos el ahoracado totalmente vacío, solo base y poste, para ello llamamos al método dibujo inicial
                                         dibujoAhorcado = dibujoInicial();
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcado[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                     //segundo fallo
                                     case 6:
                                         //vamos a por el dibujo del ahorcado, enviamos por parámetro el dibujo a elegir y la opción
                                         dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(0, 0);
                                         //sustituimos el valor del dibujo inicial por las del ahorcado en función de los fallos, para ello se llama al método dibuja ahorcado y se envía por parámetro el array dibujo ahorcado juego, el string debujo ahorcado F y la opción
                                         dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 0);
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                     case 5:
                                         dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(1, 0);
                                         dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 1);
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                          System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                     case 4:
                                         dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(2, 0);
                                         dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 2);
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                     case 3:
                                         //para los errores tres y cuatro, utilizamos la misma posición del array ahorcado juego, pero distanta posición del array ahoracado f, así que le enviamos la opción 0 ó 1 para cambiar el valor elegido en el array
                                         dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(3, 0);
                                         dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 3);
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                     case 2:
                                         dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(3, 1); 
                                         dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 3);
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                     case 1:
                                         dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(4, 0);
                                         dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 4);
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
                                             System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
                                         }
                                         System.out.println("");
                                         break;
                                 }
                                 //si la letra no está en la palabra descontamos un vida
                                 vidas--;
                             } 
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 else{
                     //Si se han acabo los huecos, quiere decir que se ha completado la palabra, por lo que escribir resulta y enhorabuena
                     System.out.println("Palabra resuelta, enhorabuena !!!");
                     System.out.println("");
                     //ponemos la variable booelana resuelto a true para evitar que vuelva a entrar en el bucle while
                     resuelto = true;
                 }
             }
             //si se ha quedado sin vidas
             if (vidas == 0){
                 //informamos al jugador del agotamiento de las mismas
                 System.out.println("Lamentablemene, sus vidas se han agotado");
                 System.out.println("");
             } 
             //una vez finalizado el juego damos la opción de iniciarlo de nuevo o salir 
             System.out.println("");
             System.out.println("Pulse 'j' para volver a jugar o 's' para salir");
             char l = teclado.next().charAt(0);
             //en función de la opción elegida
             if (l == 's'){
                 //cerramos teclado y finalizamos aplicación
                 teclado.close();
                 System.exit(0);
             }
             else if (l == 'j'){
                 //creamoa un nuevo array de caracteres vacío y lo enviamos por parámetro para uniciar de nuevo el juego
                 char[] palabraII = {};
                 metodoMenu(palabraII);
             }
         }
     //método para añadir la palabra
     public static char[] añadirPalabra() {
         //limpiamos el bufer del teclado
         teclado.nextLine();
             //pedimos la palabra
             System.out.println("Jugador 1 introduzca la palabra deseada (sin numeros ni espacios)");
             //capturamos la palabra en la variable palabra inicial
             palabraInicial = teclado.nextLine();
             //aquí podría incluirse un método para evaluar que los caracteres que se introduzcan por teclado sean solo letrase independientemente de que sean mayúsuclas o minúsculas siga funcionando el programa
             String palabraAux = palabraInicial;
             //palabraInicial = "";

             //creamos el array de caracteres con la palabra introducida por teclado
             char[] palabra = palabraInicial.toCharArray();
             //retornamos el array
             return palabra;
     }
     public static byte menu() {
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("MENU");
         System.out.println("1. Ingresa Palabra");
         System.out.println("2. Jugar");
         System.out.println("3. Salir");
         System.out.println("");
         System.out.println("Porfavor seleccione una opcion: ");
         return teclado.nextByte();
     }
     //dibujo inicial del ahorcado vacío
     public static String[] dibujoInicial () {
         //creamos el array del dibujo almacenando cada línea en una posición del array
         String[] dibujoAhorcado = new String[6];

         dibujoAhorcado[0] = "|";
         dibujoAhorcado[1] = "|";
         dibujoAhorcado[2] = "|";
         dibujoAhorcado[3] = "|";
         dibujoAhorcado[4] = "|";
         dibujoAhorcado[5] = "|_______";
        
         return dibujoAhorcado;
     }
    //método del dibujo final del juego
    public static String dibujoFinal (int valor, int control) {
        String dibujo = "";
        String[] dibujoAhorcadoF = new String[6];

        dibujoAhorcadoF[0] = "|---";
        dibujoAhorcadoF[1] = "|  |";
        dibujoAhorcadoF[2] = "|  o";
        if (control == 0){
            dibujoAhorcadoF[3] = "|  |";
        }
        else {
            dibujoAhorcadoF[3] = "| /|\\";
        }
        dibujoAhorcadoF[4] = "| / \\";
        dibujoAhorcadoF[5] = "|_______";
        
        dibujo = dibujoAhorcadoF[valor];    
        return dibujo;
    }
    //método que va dibujando el ahorcado según los fallos
    private static String[] metodoDibujaAhorcado(String[] dibujoAhorcado, String dibujoAhorcadoF, int vidas) {

        dibujoAhorcado[vidas] = dibujoAhorcadoF;
        return dibujoAhorcado;
    }
}
```

Como podrás comprobar es un ejercicio ya con cierta dificultad y bastante extenso. Quizás no sea el ideal para iniciarse en la programación, aunque tampoco conozco tu nivel. El caso es que casi me resulta más difícil intentar explicar que es lo que hace cada parte del código que luego programarlo.

En todo caso, espero te sirva de base y lo puedas ir adaptando a tus necesidades

insisto en que lo he programado y probado con alguna palabra concreta, y no sabría decirte si pueden salir errores, pues no he resalizado el test de pruebas necesario

un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió mucho como base para seguir con mi código