# Se podría comprimir éste conjunto de condiciones a la mínima expresión?

Tags: java, bucle-for

Tras dar un repaso a las últimas respuestas publicadas del lenguaje java, que es mi método para profundizar en mis conocimientos de dicho lenguaje, me encontré con un código de @el.trasgu, que con su permiso, me gustaría intentar comprimir, pues creo que podría ser posible y disminuiría y optimizaría mucho el código del programa

Su respuesta era para solucionar el juego del ahorcado, juego que por cierto me encanta y su solución funciona a la perfección

el código al que me refiero sería:

```
switch (vidas){
    //en el primer fallo
        case 7:
        //dibujamos el ahoracado totalmente vacío, solo base y poste, para ello llamamos al método dibujo inicial
        dibujoAhorcado = dibujoInicial();
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
            System.out.print(dibujoAhorcado[k] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    //segundo fallo
    case 6:
        //vamos a por el dibujo del ahorcado, enviamos por parámetro el dibujo a elegir y la opción
        dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(0, 0);
        //sustituimos el valor del dibujo inicial por las del ahorcado en función de los fallos, para ello se llama al método dibuja ahorcado y se envía por parámetro el array dibujo ahorcado juego, el string debujo ahorcado F y la opción
        dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 0);
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
            System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    case 5:
        dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(1, 0);
        dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 1);
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
            System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    case 4:
        dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(2, 0);
        dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 2);
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
            System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        break;
    case 3:
       //para los errores tres y cuatro, utilizamos la misma posición del array ahorcado juego, pero distanta posición del array ahoracado f, así que le enviamos la opción 0 ó 1 para cambiar el valor elegido en el array
       dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(3, 0);
       dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 3);
       System.out.println("");
       for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
           System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
       }
       System.out.println("");
       break;
   case 2:
       dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(3, 1); 
       dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 3);
       System.out.println("");
       for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
           System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
       }
       System.out.println("");
       break;
   case 1:
       dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(4, 0);
       dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 4);
       System.out.println("");
       for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcado.length; k++){
           System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
       }
       System.out.println("");
       break;
   }
vidas--;
```

El código de toda la respuesta estaría en el siguiente enlace:

[Código juego del Ahorcado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465021/c%C3%B3mo-se-retorna-una-funci%C3%B3n-correctamente/465259#465259)

El primer paso que se me ocurrió, fué eliminar el código para imprimir que se repetía en cada case del Swintch

```
    switch (vidas){
        //en el primer fallo
        case 7:
            //dibujamos el ahoracado totalmente vacío, solo base y poste, para ello llamamos al método dibujo inicial
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = dibujoInicial();
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
            break;
        //segundo fallo
            case 6:
            //vamos a por el dibujo del ahorcado, enviamos por parámetro el dibujo a elegir y la opción
            dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(0, 0);
            //sustituimos el valor del dibujo inicial por las del ahorcado en función de los fallos, para ello se llama al método dibuja ahorcado y se envía por parámetro el array dibujo ahorcado juego, el string debujo ahorcado F y la opción
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 0);
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
            break;
        case 5:
            dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(1, 0);
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 1);
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
            break;
        case 4:
            dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(2, 0);
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 2);
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
            break;
        case 3:
            //para los errores tres y cuatro, utilizamos la misma posición del array ahorcado juego, pero distanta posición del array ahoracado f, así que le enviamos la opción 0 ó 1 para cambiar el valor elegido en el array
            dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(3, 0);
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 3);
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
            break;
        case 2:
            dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(3, 1); 
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 3);
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
            break;
        case 1:
            dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(4, 0);
            dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 4);
            metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
        break;
    }
```

y crear el método para imprimir el dibujo:

```
    private static void metodoImprimeAhorcado(String[] dibujoAhorcadoJuego){
        System.out.println("");
        for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcadoJuego.length; k++){
            System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Pero ahora llegaría el tema más complicado para mí. Sería posible sustituir ese switch por un bucle teniendo en cuenta que los case se decrementan y los parámetros se incrementan y además uno se repite ?

Yo he programado éste for, pero me da varios errores, y me pierdo al intentar resolverlos

```
    vidas = 7;
    int contador = 0;
    for (int v = vidas; v > 0; v--){
        if (contador == 0){
             dibujoAhorcadoJuego = dibujoInicial();
             metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
        }
        else {
             dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(contador, 0);
             dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, 1);
             metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
       }
       contador++;
   }
```

errores:

```
*Exception in thread "main"    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

    at variosprogramacion.AhorcadoII.dibujoFinal(AhorcadoII.java:249)
    at variosprogramacion.AhorcadoII.iniciarJuego(AhorcadoII.java:149)
    at variosprogramacion.AhorcadoII.metodoMenu(AhorcadoII.java:53)
    at variosprogramacion.AhorcadoII.metodoMenu(AhorcadoII.java:46)
    at variosprogramacion.AhorcadoII.main(AhorcadoII.java:23)
Java Result: 1*
```

gracias

Comment: Te faltó incluir en la pregunta los errores que te da tu código.

Comment: Vaya, gracias por citarme y usar mi código, aunque no se si sentirme alagado o humillado por la de líneas que has conseguido reducir por mi mala optimización. Aunque considero que aquí estamos todos para aprender, y ésta, será sin duda para mí una lección más de mucho interés. Gracias @Vanessa, estaré atento a tus progresos.

Comment: @el.trasgu, por favor, no lo tomes a mal, en ningún momento pretendo dejar en evidencia tu código, simplemente la posibilidad de optimizar un programa que considero muy interesante y funcional. Gracias por tu comprensión.

Comment: El switch solito no equivale a un bucle, pero la naturaleza del juego es que itera N veces hasta que se queda sin intentos y se ahorca. Ya si valida las vidas ahí o "más afuera", eso ya es un detalle de implementación. En el código que cita, efectivamente la iteración de vidas se hace afuera.

Comment: El switch no es un ciclo y por eso no deberías sustituirlo con uno; si bien puede verse como una sucesión de ifs, requeriría una condición de salida. Por otro lado, el código sí puede reducirse a un par de líneas, analiza: `dibujoFinal(6-vidas, vidas==2?1:0)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios y aclaraciones, así da gusto ir aprendiendo de mis errores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pues después de pelearme toda la tarde con el código y el reto personal de eliminar el switch y comprimir el código lo máximo que se me ha podido ocurrir, tengo lo siguiente:

```
//declaro variables de contadores fuera del bucle while:
int contador = 0;
int contador4 = 0; 
int subcontador = 0;

//sustituyo todo el bloque switch por:
//si el contador está a cero, primer fallo en letra errónea
if (contador == 0){
    //dibujo el Ahorcado inicial
    dibujoAhorcadoJuego = dibujoInicial();
    metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
}
else {
    //Ahora haciendo uso de los distintos contadores voy validando en función de lo que deseo mostrar en el dibujo del ahorcado teniendo en cuenta los fallos
    if ((contador == 4) && (contador4 == 0) && (subcontador == 0) || (subcontador == 1)){
        dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(contador - 1, subcontador);
        dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, contador - 1);
        metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
        contador4 = 1;
        if (subcontador == 0){
            //como dibujo dos veces seguidas haciendo uso de la misma línea del array, lo que hago es descontar 1 al contador para repetir línea
            contador--;
        }
        subcontador++;
    }
    else {
        //en el resto de casos que no se cumplen en las dos evaluacioes anteriores
        dibujoAhorcadoF = dibujoFinal(contador - 1, 0);
        dibujoAhorcadoJuego = metodoDibujaAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego, dibujoAhorcadoF, contador - 1);
        metodoImprimeAhorcado(dibujoAhorcadoJuego);
    }           
}
//aumento contador y disminuyo vidas
contador++;
vidas--;
```

Seguro que se podrá comprimir aún más y de otras formas, pero mi cabeza no da para más. Solo teniendo en cuenta el bloque switch se han reducido alrededor de 40 líneas y se ha automatizado el proceso, pues antes el cada case se metía cada opción a mano y ahora se va generando de forma iterativa

Para el dibujo del ahorcado hice uso del método creado por @Vanessa

```
private static void metodoImprimeAhorcado(String[] dibujoAhorcadoJuego){
    System.out.println("");
    for (int k = 0; k < dibujoAhorcadoJuego.length; k++){
        System.out.print(dibujoAhorcadoJuego[k] + "\n");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Por cierto, el bucle no tendría sentido, yo supongo que te confundirías en su utilidad por la iteración en las opciones del case (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...) pero esa no sería iteración, si no el número de errores o fallos con cada letra y el número de posición que se pide según ese número de fallos al array del dibujo del ahorcado.

Si metemos ese bucle aquí, lo que conseguiríamos sería imprimir todos los niveles del ahorcado por cada letra errónea

Un saludo

Comment: Pues muchas gracias @el.trasgu. Sin pretenderlo creo que te puse en apuros, pero bueno, me alegra que hayas sido tú mismo quien me ha sacado de mis dudas. Eres un sol

Comment: Tremenda respuesta! :)

Comment: Guauuu, no se si me ha gustado más el reto que podría suponer la pregunta, o la aceptación del mismo por parte de @el.trasgu. El caso es que me ha encantado el desafío. Os imagináis una nueva pestaña de retos, en la que a diferencia de responder las preguntas de las dudas, que generalmente suelen ser siempre las mismas con diferentes matices, se vayan subiendo retos semanales o mensuales para la consecución de un objetivo ? Creo que podría ser un estímulo sobre todo para la gente que lleva tiempo en la comunidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

En el código de @el.trasgu el método dibujo final es más o menos así

```
        String[] dibujoAhorcadoF = new String[6];

        dibujoAhorcadoF[0] = "|---";
        dibujoAhorcadoF[1] = "|  |";
        dibujoAhorcadoF[2] = "|  o";
        if (control == 0){
            dibujoAhorcadoF[3] = "|  |";
        }
        else {
            dibujoAhorcadoF[3] = "| /|\\";
        }
        dibujoAhorcadoF[4] = "| / \\";
        dibujoAhorcadoF[5] = "|_______";
        
        dibujo = dibujoAhorcadoF[valor];
```

Vemos que `dibujoAhorcadoF` es de longitud 6 (de cero a cinco).

Tu `contador` inicia en cero y se incrementa en uno por cada iteración del for. Eventualmente llegará a seis (cuando v sea 1, creo) y ahí `valor` de ese método dibujoFinal será seis. Estarás buscando en la posición 6 de `dibujoAhorcadoF`, que no existe.